# How to define different screens in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've just started to get familiar with Jetpack Compose and from what I understand, a NavHost is like a NavHostFragment, it hosts different composables rather than fragments.

What I'm struggling to understand is that if I define a screen with a scaffold and a NavHost as its content like:

```
setContent{
    Scaffold(...){
         NavHost(...){...}
    }
}
```

That makes the bottom nav bar and everything defined in the scaffold appear for every single composable hosted by the NavHost. What if I want to have different floating action buttons for different screens? Do I have to start a new activity for those screens and define a different scaffold there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually reference the navHostController. You can either keep track of the current screen by updating a variable everytime you navigate or just use navController.getCurrentBackStackEntry?.destination to get the current screen. Use this inside your floating action button to set it accordingly

Comment: I see.. so I just get the current route and set the FAB content according to the screen I am on. Thanks!

Comment: It's wonderful that your problem is solved. You should mark my answer as the solution so that others know that the question has been answered, and do not answer multiple times, thanks